# Grouping common attributes in GridView

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, database, gridview

Alright, so I have a database and a ASP.NET using C# as the code behind. What I'm having trouble with is getting the asp GridView to display the database query like I need it to. Here is some sample information:

I have users, groups, projects, and permissions. Currently the output looks like this:

```
John    JohnsGroup1
John    JohnsGroup2
Eric    EricsGroup1
```

With every permission and user having its own row.

What I want is to group all of a user's groups into one cell like this:

```
John    JohnsGroup1
        JohnsGroup2
Eric    EricsGroup1
```

Here is my query running from code behind:

```
"select Users.name, Groups.name from Users join Permissions on Users.ID = Permissions.userID, Groups where Groups.ProjectID = " + projID + " and Groups.type = '3' and Permissions.groupID = Groups.ID order by name";
```

Any ideas? I'm trying to avoid looping through the data after it's queried to sort it.